# excel: looking up values using INDEX

Tags: excel, lookup

i am using the following formula to index my data on sheet 2 and find the matching values which are similar or exact to that which is typed into my cell K22 on sheet 1.

I have used the below code and combined it together using & statements to give me multiple results from seperate columns.

=`IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,5)=LEFT(Sheet1!$K$22,5),ROW($A$1:$D$10004)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,5)=LEFT(Sheet1!$K$22,5),ROW($A$1:$D$10004)),ROW(1:1)),1))`

so my finished combined code looks like this:

```
=`IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,5)=LEFT(Sheet1!$K$22,5),ROW($A$1:$D$10004)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,5)=LEFT(Sheet1!$K$22,5),ROW($A$1:$D$10004)),ROW(1:1)),1)) & " - " & IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,5)=RIGHT(Sheet1!$K$22,5),ROW($A$1:$D$10004)),ROW(1:1)),3)),"",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,5)=RIGHT(Sheet1!$K$22,5),ROW($A$1:$D$10004)),ROW(1:1)),3)) & " - " & IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,5)=LEFT(Sheet1!$K$22,5),ROW($A$1:$D$10004)),ROW(1:1)),4)),"",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10004,5)=LEFT(Sheet1!$K$22,5),ROW($A$1:$D$10004)),ROW(1:1)),4))
```

so when i perform a search this displays the results like so

```
Supplier x - Manchester - V0001
```

i am using ROW() function because i have many of these formulas in seperate rows on my sheet to return multiple search results.

i am also using LEFT() function as a way of telling it to find similar results rather than exact, because someone may type 'Hotel' instead of 'Hotels' etc.

my data on sheet 2 looks like this:

```
Name          Description    Location       Number
Supplier X    Catering       Manchester     v0001
Supplier Y    Hotels         London         v0002
Supplier Z    Catering       London         v0003
```

so if i do a search for catering in my cell K22 on sheet 1 i would get a result like this:

```
Supplier X - Manchester - V0001
Supplier Z - London - V0003
```

But now if i want to just search for catering suppliers in London, i get the same search results again:

```
Supplier X - London - V0001
Supplier Z - London - V0003
```

however it changes the location of supplier x from manchester to london, even though in my column data on sheet 2, supplier x location is manchester?

Can someone please show me why this is happening as it should only be returning the suppliers which have a matching location of London next to them.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Instead of working with such a complex formula, which is difficult to debug and maintain, why not set things up so you can return your results using a filter?  You could also use dropdowns for the selections, so as not have to worry about misspellings.

Comment: Please respond to answers on previous questions before posting more